# AppIcon overlay is not working in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, sh, appicon

Recently I was searching something great for my app, and I found that I can add an overlay to AppIcon for different Configuration of the project. But it is not working in Xcode 9.2 with iOS 11.2.2.

Here is what Tested.
Using [Amaro](https://github.com/crushlovely/Amaro) I can get an overlay of version and build with the configuration in Xcode 8.3.2 with simulator iPhone 6s.

[image: iOS 10.3, 6s Simulator]

But not getting in my iPhone 6 (iOS 11.2.2 with Xcode 9.2)

[image: iOS 11.2, iPhone 6]

I've also visited [here](http://engineering.tispr.com/blog/2015/08/02/how-to-display-build-number-and-version-on-an-ios-app-icon/) and [here](http://merowing.info/2013/03/overlaying-application-version-on-top-of-your-icon/)  but not getting anything which is compatible with Xcode 9.2

Please help me to find solutions for this issue.

Comment: I wanted to do this but I think it is too much trouble, install tools etc, specially if you have a CI or something. What you can do is change the name app (without the need to create a new target) take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/swift2go/different-app-display-name-based-on-xcode-scheme-d709307d0c01)